# Microstate counting in 1D Ising model with long range interaction

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

I have a question about microstate counting, which came up while working a problem in *Equilibrium Statistical Physics* by Plischke and Bergersen. In the problem we study a one-dimensional Ising model with long range interaction, having the hamiltonian

$$H = -\frac{J}{2} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j \ne i} \frac{\sigma_i \sigma_j}{|i-j|^\alpha}, \tag 1$$

where the spins $\sigma_i$ take values $\pm 1$, and where $\alpha \in (1,2)$ and $J > 0$ are constants.

Consider a hypothetical transition from the ground state (all spins up or all spins down) to a two-domain state, where we have a domain wall separating a domain of up-spins from a domain of down-spins. A first approach to calculating the associated entropy difference would be to note that there are $N-1$ places to put the domain wall, and then two choices for which side of the wall is spin up. Hence,

$$\Delta S = k_B \ln[2(N-1)] \approx k_B \ln N. \tag 2$$

However, it is clear from (1) (even without doing the calculation) that different placements of the domain wall will give different energy differences $\Delta E$. Consider for example placing the domain wall close to an end of the chain (low $\Delta E$), versus placing it in the middle (high $\Delta E$).

Does this not make the different placements distinguishable, i.e. different macrostates? If so, then there are really just 2 possible wall placements for a particular $\Delta E$ ($n$ places from one end or the other) and then 2 choices for which domain is spin up, yielding instead

$$\Delta S = k_B \ln 4. \tag 3$$

Which approach to counting microstates is the correct one? Does it depend on what we can measure? This issue does not appear in the Ising model with only nearest-neighbor interaction, since then every wall placement yields the same $\Delta E$.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the condition $a < 2$, the domain wall located far from the boundaries is an excitation with very high energy at $N\to\infty$. The reason lies in the following asymptotic of the sum associated with the excitation energy
$$
\sum_{i = 0}^{xN}\sum_{j=0}^{(1-x)N} \frac1{(i+j+1)^a} \sim N^{2-a}
$$
where $x\in(0,1)$ is fixed, while $N\to \infty$. So I'm not sure if domain wall type excitations are relevant to the problem you want to solve. I think that the elementary excitations in this problem are finite clusters of flipped spins in a sea of identically oriented spins. The simplest excitation of this type with probably the lowest energy, a single inverted spin at a distance of $xN$ from the left boundary, has an energy almost independent of $x$ at $N\to\infty$:
$$
\Delta E = 2J\left(\sum_{i=1}^{xN}\frac1{i^a} + \sum_{i=1}^{(1-x)N} \frac1{i^a}\right) \approx 4J\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac1{i^a}
$$
And we have almost $N$ such ecxcitations.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I know that $\Delta E = O(N^{2-\alpha})$ and hence that large domains will not form for large $N$, whether one counts as (2) or as (3). That was what the actual problem was about, and I did solve it. My question is more of a follow up; and we could certainly imagine other interactions and other excitations where it becomes relevant how one counts the microstates.

Comment: In fact we could ask the question about state counting for your example with a single inverted spin. While there are indeed $N$ such excitations, they again have slightly different energies $\Delta E$ depending on closeness to the ends of the chain. Hence, should we count them as different macrostates when it comes to determining $\Delta S$?

Comment: Macroscopic degeneracy of states is a feature of the Ising and Potts models with the interaction of nearest neighbors. In more realistic models, we count states from an energy interval of nonzero width when calculating $\Gamma$. So I think your formula (2) is more relevant.